# modify the HTC unlock system on an HTC Android 2.3.5 phone?

Tags: htc-sense, lock-screens, htc, menu

My HTC Unlock system comes with "Phone", "Mail", "Camera" and "Messages" options on top of the bubble-thingy that one has to move around to unlock. How can I modify the options in this menu to add new app icons or remove any of these four?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Long tap in your main launcher window --> (Personalize menu pops)--> click on "Display" --> Lockscreen --> Settings.

You can only switch between application, but you cannot have more than 4.

Comment: This option has unfortunately disappeared in Android 4.0